# jquery filter: find the match and trigger click

Tags: jquery, filter, eventtrigger, jquery-1.9

I want to find the match in the link and then trigger the click event on it.

jquery,

```
var request = 'id=10';
var test = $("a").filter("[href*=" + request + "]").trigger('click');
```

html,

```
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=10&ajax=true">1</a>
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=20&ajax=true">2</a>
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=30&ajax=true">3</a>
```

error message,

```
unrecognised expression:[href*=id=50]
```

I tried with this one below but failed too,

```
var test = $("a").filter("[href*=http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=10&ajax=true]").trigger('click');
```

How should the expression be in this case?

If possible, I would like to match the whole thing, like,

```
http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=10&ajax=true
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the request match with quotes:

```
$('a[href*="id=10"]').trigger('click');
```